# What is wrong with the session variables

Tags: php, forms, redirect, post, session-variables

I have no idea whats wrong with the session variables in my code...Here is a snippet:

file 1:

```
display_test();

    function display_test(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['testing']['testing'])) echo $_SESSION['testing']['testing'];

        echo "<br><br><br><form id=\"current_juices_form\" method=\"post\" action=\"file2.php\">
                <input type=\"submit\" />
             </form>";
    }
```

File 2(the file the above form is getting submitted too):

```
testing();

function testing(){
    unset($_SESSION);
    $_SESSION['testing']['testing'] = "<br>testing<br>";
    header("Location:  file1.php");
}
```

For some reason when redirecting back to file1 after file2 is done processing post action, it's not printing out the session variable $_SESSION['testing']['testing']...what is going on???

Comment: do you have session_start(); within both files?

Comment: yes, i double checked...

Comment: are you calling/return'ing the function(s)?

Comment: yes just tested with a return statement at end of each function.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: ok i turned on all error reporting(exactly like ur code) and still not working..

Comment: [PHP doc: do **NOT** `unset($_SESSION)`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php#refsect1-function.session-unset-notes).

Comment: ^ I thought that too.

Comment: ok after removing unset, and turning all error report, i get this message:

Comment: I'd also add an `else{ echo "Not set"; }` while using bracing for your `if{...}` and adding `exit;` after header; this as a sidenote. If it goes in the `else{...}` and it echo's, it's not set.

Comment: Warning: Illegal string offset 'testing'

Comment: i thought in php u can use a variable even if it's not been set?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is true, but I believe using `unset($_SESSION)` would affect the superglobal range of the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need initialize the $_SESSION['testing'] first.

```
function testing(){
    if (!isset($_SESSION['testing'])) {
        $_SESSION['testing'] = Array();
    }

    $_SESSION['testing']['testing'] = "<br>testing<br>";
    header("Location:  file1.php");
}
```

Or you can do this as well:

```
function testing(){        
    $_SESSION['testing'] = Array('testing' => "<br>testing<br>");
    header("Location:  file1.php");
}
```

Comment: i c what ur saying, but in other parts of my code, i never initialized a two-d session variable, and they always worked...id post the other code, but its under nda..